# Maven build error - can't deploy zip to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, aio

We're unable to deploy a zip file to the AWS S3 bucket. It was working and stopped suddenly, and no environment changed. We're getting the below build error.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file (default-cli) on project aem-coe-project: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    16:58:27   Info     |       [ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
    16:58:27   Info     |       [ERROR] realm =
    
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
    16:58:27   Info     |       [ERROR] urls[0] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/2.7/maven-deploy-plugin-2.7.jar
    16:58:27   Info     |       [ERROR] urls[1] = file:/root/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
    16:58:27   Info     |       [ERROR] urls[2] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.6/plexus-utils-1.5.6.jar
    16:58:27   Info     |       [ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
    16:58:27   Info     |       [ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[project>com.coe:aem-coe-project:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]]
    16:58:27   Info     |       [ERROR]
    16:58:27   Info     |       [ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
    16:58:27   Info     |       [ERROR] : javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
```

Below is the build section of `pom.xml`.

```
<extensions>
  <extension>
    <groupId>s3-wagon-private</groupId>
    <artifactId>s3-wagon-private</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
  </extension>
</extensions>
```

Could you please suggest me here?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `A required class was missing` and `javax/xml/bind/JAXBException` pointing to the same place. There might be a SOAP-Service that changed. Check the APIs you consume and the ones you offer.